# Display tick image when click color for a particular id

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to display tick image when click one color which is a background color.
My phtml coding is

```
<?php foreach($this->getSolidColors() as $key => $_solidColors) : ?>
    <li id="font-colr-<?php echo $_solidColors['id'] ?>" onclick="selectcolor("<?php echo $_solidColors['id'] ?>");" data-id="<?php echo $_solidColors['id'] ?>" data-img="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/images/checked.png'); ?>" class="cursor font-color" style="background: #<?php echo $_solidColors['hexa'] ?>" data-color="#<?php echo $_solidColors['hexa'] ?>">
        <span class="sprite"></span>
        <img id="tick" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/images/checked.png'); ?>" width="80%" height="80%" style="display:none; padding-left:10px;">
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

```js
function selectcolor() {
    var id = jQuery('#font-colr').attr('data-id');
    jQuery('#tick').css('display', 'block');
}
```

When I click particular color the tick image is displayed for the first color only but I want to get image for which color I clicked and if I select another color the previous tick mark should be disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that the `id` of 'tick' is repeated throughout your page, which is invalid as `id` must be unique. You should change that to a common `class` instead.

You should also use unobtrusive JS to attach your event handlers instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes. Try this:

```html
<?php foreach($this->getSolidColors() as $key => $_solidColors) : ?>
    <li class="cursor font-color" id="font-colr-<?php echo $_solidColors['id'] ?>" data-id="<?php echo $_solidColors['id'] ?>" data-img="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/images/checked.png'); ?>"  style="background: #<?php echo $_solidColors['hexa'] ?>" data-color="#<?php echo $_solidColors['hexa'] ?>">
        <span class="sprite"></span>
        <img class="tick" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/images/checked.png'); ?>">
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

```css
.tick {
    width: 80%; 
    height: 80%
    display: none; 
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```js
$('li.font-color').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); // I presume you use this value somewhere in your code?
    $(this).find('.tick').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. i have one more issue if i tick another then previous tick should be removed what should i do for this

Comment: Add `$('.tick').hide()` after setting `var id = ...`

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique.  In your loop, add a unique id for each tick:

```
  <li id="font-colr-<?php echo $_solidColors['id'] ?>" onclick="selectcolor("<?php echo $_solidColors['id'] ?>");" data-id="<?php echo $_solidColors['id'] ?>" data-img="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/images/checked.png'); ?>"
        class="cursor font-color" 
        style="background: #<?php echo $_solidColors['hexa'] ?>"
        data-color="#<?php echo $_solidColors['hexa'] ?>">
   <span class="sprite"></span>
   <img id="tick-<?php echo $_solidColors['id'] ?>" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/images/checked.png'); ?>" width="80%" height="80%" style="display:none; padding-left:10px;">
  </li>
```

and in your selectColor where you pass the id, use it:

```
function selectcolor(id){
  jQuery('#tick-'+id).css('display', 'block');
}
```